# Error C0190019 applying update operation 6503 of 138763 (SettingSync.dll)

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-update

Recently I was trying to update my Windows 8.1. I downloaded the update and started update process. As soon the the installations started I encountered the error mentioned above.

[image]

I did some research and found the solution.
I will provide the solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs due to limited/no space in the C drive for the update to be installed.

> You have to free up some space (around 3-4 GB) for the installation to
>   continue To check the space available on C, you have to go to advanced
>   option. Since the bootup failed the windows will automatically try to
>   repair (which fails). You will be presented with two options Restart/Shutdown and
>   Advanced Options

- Select **Advanced Options**
- Click on **Troubleshoot**
- Again select **Advanced Options**
- Slect **Command Prompt**
- Login with your credentials if prompted and type `notepad.exe`
- This will open up the notepad application, use **File** -> **Open**
- In explorer go to **My Computer** and check the free space in C
- Free up the space as needed by deleting/moving files from C Drive
- In case you can't delete or free up some space, try to reduce the page file or disable hibernation
- `powercfg.exe /hibernate off`

Answer (score -1):

This would be great if I could get past the error and into windows....
So my solution is the pull the hard drive out and mount it another pc via my hard drive to usb adapter. Then I can go into the file system and do my own custom cleaning of .CAB files from the temp folder. Usually works for me.
Make sure you get a SATA and PATA compatible adapter.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).